# Typescript Unions - "property does not exist on type" error

Tags: typescript, union-types

I have experimented with creating custom types recently and doing so, I came across an error which I really do not understand. Assume the following setup:

##### Type Definitions

```js
type Error = {
  error: string
}

type Item = {
  id: string
  name: string
}

type Result = Item | Error
```

##### Test Function

```js
const testFunc = ( item: boolean ): Result => {
  return item ? { id: '0x1', name: 'My Item' } : { error: 'An error has occurred }; 
}
```

##### Progam

```js
const item = testFunc(true);
if ( item.error ) {          // <-- TS complains that `error` does not exist on type `Result`
  console.log('error');
}
console.log('Happy days!', item)
```

TS keeps complaining that

`Property 'error' does not exist on type 'Response'.`

`Property 'error' does not exist on type 'Item'.ts(2339)`

If I remove `Item` from `Result` it obviously works. Do I have something misconfigured or do I get this completely wrong? I have basically read through [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html) and thought that this should be a very easy task.

Thanks! Any help appreciated!

Comment: You would need a type-guard or a condition like `'error' in item`

Comment: Union means either of them or both of them. So it’s not guaranteed to have the error property, it just can have the error property. You need to check what you have.

Comment: Thanks for the very quick response! Your comments make total sense and it pushed me into the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a type guard before accessing a property or a method that is not common to all the types in your Union Type.

In this case, the easiest would probably to check whether your `item` has a property named `error`:

```js
const item = testFunc(true);
if ( 'error' in item ) {
  console.log(item.error);
} else {
  console.log('Happy days!', item)
}
```

If you were using classes instead of types, you could also use `if(item instanceof MyError)` instead of `if ( 'error' in item )`.

If you types were primitive (boolean, string, number), you could also use `if(typeof item === 'string')` instead of `if ( 'error' in item )`.

*BTW, as @CertainPerformance mentioned, don't use `Error`.*

Comment: Using type guards for me seems to be "the most elegant" solution! Thanks for that! This is more or less the way I did proceed with.

Answer (score 2):

By specifying that the return type of the function is `Result`, the returned `item` is inferred to be (due to how you've specified the type):

```
{ error: string }
| { id: string, name: string }
```

TypeScript doesn't go into the local paths of the function and narrow down the type of the possible return value, not without overloading or generics or something.

You can fix this by removing your annotated type-widening so that TS can infer that the return value is of type:

```
{
    id: string;
    name: string;
    error?: undefined;
} | {
    error: string;
    id?: undefined;
    name?: undefined;
}
```

Which is easier to work with than your original types, because possibly having properties whose values are `undefined` means that those properties are easily accessible. (In contrast, something like `{ id: string; name: string }` does not have the `error` property at all, so `error` can't be accessed on it without narrowing down the type first, like with `in`)

I'd also recommend not using `type Error` - don't shadow the global `Error`, call it something else.

```
const testFunc = (item: boolean) => {
    return item ? { id: '0x1', name: 'My Item' } : {
        error: 'An error has occurred'
    };
}
```

will compile successfully.

Comment: This is the first thing I had implemented. Somehow, I don't like the fact that I would have to repeat my type props plus I also want to use my `Error` type with more than one function and thus I'd have to add more and more props. And yes, `type Error` is very bad and I have just used it for the example here.

Answer (score 1):

When you get a type that has union of different types and you are trying to access it - the type system needs to know which type of "this multi-types / unions do you mean?" because it cannot know what are trying to reference.

You can one of this solutions below:

- TypeCasting the variables when you want to access it as error `if ((item as Error).error) {}`
- TypeCasting the return `const item = testFunc(true) as Error`

Comment: Good approach but if I typecast `item` as `Error` I would not be able to access `Item` without typecasting it again.